# generics with subclass

Tags: java

I have three different types of parameters: int, float and long. I want to use an object to represent each of them. So i have one abstract class:

```
abstract public class AbstractProtocolParamObj<T extends Number>
{
    public enum ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum
    {
        None,
        OnOff,
        Values,
        ValueRange,
        ValueRangeIncrement
    }

    protected String name;
    protected ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum constraintValueType;
    protected Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> dependentParams;
    protected Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> constraintParams;
    protected T value;

    protected AbstractProtocolParamObj(String name, 
            ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum constraintValueType,
            T value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.constraintValueType = constraintValueType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public final String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public final ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum getConstraintValueType()
    {
        return constraintValueType;
    }

    public void addDependentParam(AbstractProtocolParamObj<T> param)
    {
        if(dependentParams == null)
        {
            dependentParams = new Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>>();
        }
        dependentParams.add(param);
    }

    public void addConstraintParam(AbstractProtocolParamObj<T> param)
    {
        if(constraintParams == null)
        {
            constraintParams = new Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>>();
        }
        constraintParams.add(param);
    }

    public Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> getDependentParams()
    {
        return dependentParams;
    }

    public Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> getConstraintParams()
    {
        return constraintParams;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T val)
    {
        value = val;
    }

    abstract public ReturnStatusEnum validate(T tempVal);   
}
```

Then I will have one class for float parameters, one class for int and one for long. Like this:

```
    public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj
{
    private float[] constraintVals;
    private float maxVal;
    private float minVal;
    private float increment;

    public ProtocolFloatParamObj(String name,
                            float value,
                            float[] constraintVals,
                            ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum constraintType
    )
    {
        super(name, constraintType, value);
         this.constraintVals = constraintVals;
    }

    public ProtocolFloatParamObj(String name,
            float value,
            float maxVal,
            float minVal,
            ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum constraintType
    )
    {
        super(name, constraintType, value);
        this.maxVal = maxVal;
        this.minVal = minVal;
    }

    public ProtocolFloatParamObj(String name,
            float value,
            float maxVal,
            float minVal,
            float increment,
            ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum constraintType
    )
    {
        this(name, value, maxVal, minVal, constraintType);
        this.increment = increment;  
    }

    @Override
    public ReturnStatusEnum validate(Number val)
    {
        ReturnStatusEnum status = ReturnStatusEnum.SUCCESS;
        float tempVal = val.floatValue();

        switch(constraintValueType)
        {
            case None:
            {
                break;
            }
            case OnOff:
            {
                break;
            }
            case Values:
            {
                                    break;
            }
            case ValueRange:
            {
                                    break;
            }
            case ValueRangeIncrement:
            {
                                    break;
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Above code has no compile error but do has warnings which complain the generic type should be parameterized in subclass at the following lines:

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj
super(name, constraintType, value);
```

But if i change

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj
```

to

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj <T extends Number> extends AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>
```

and change the constructor `value` parameter from `float` to `T`. then everything looks good without compile error and warning.

The issue is because the ProtocolFloatParamObj constructor has a T parameter, its user/caller needs to define the `T` and it's easy to get warning or compile error.

For example in another class, I try to create a Vector contains some of those parameter objs but I cannot eliminate warnings or I cannot add to the `objs` vector:

```
public Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> getAxialParamObjs()
    {
        Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>> objs = new Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<T>>();
        ProtocolFloatParamObj<T> scanSpeed = new ProtocolFloatParamObj("scanSpeed", 
                new Float(Float.parseFloat(m_axialDefaultConfig.getProperty("scanSpeed"))),
                new float[]{0.5f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f},
                ProtocolParamConstraintTypeEnum.Values
                );

        objs.add(scanSpeed);
        ......
        return objs;
    }
```

It seems this is not a good idea or i need read more about java generic.

Do you have a better idea and do you have any advanced java generic tutorial links?

Comment: `ProtocolFloatParamObj` should extend `AbstractProtocolParamObj<Float>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj<Float>
```

Which should assign Float as the type parameter T of the super class.

Comment: your suggestion works. thanks. but how to eliminate the warning in the following code: Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj> objs = new Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj>();   I cannot do the following otherwise I cannot add any ProtocolFloatParamObj into that vector: Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<Number>> objs = new Vector<AbstractProtocolParamObj<Number>>();

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
AbstractProtocolParamObj<T> to AbstractProtocolParamObj<Float>
```

and change

```
ProtocolFloatParamObj <T extends Number> to only ProtocolFloatParamObj
```

resulting in

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj<Float>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it like:

```
public class ProtocolFloatParamObj extends AbstractProtocolParamObj<Float>{
   ....
}
```